# How to fix "mapping values are not allowed in this context " error in yaml file?

Tags: yaml

I've browsed similar questions and believe i've applied all that i've been able to glean from answers.

I have a .yml file where as far as I can tell each element is formatted identically. And yet according to [YamlLint.com](http://www.yamllint.com/)

`(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 119 column 16`

In this case, line 119 is the line containing the second instance the word "transitions" below. That I can tell each element is formatted identically. Am I missing something here?

```
  landingPage:
    include: false
    transitions:
      -
        condition:location
        nextState:location

  location:
    include:false
    transitions:
      -
        condition:excluded
        nextState:excluded

  excluded:
    include:false
    transitions:
      -
        condition:excluded
        nextState: excluded
      -
        condition:age
        nextState:age
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You cannot have a multiline plain scalar, such as your `include:false transitions` be the key to a mapping, that is why you get the mapping values not allowed in this context error.

Either you forgot that you have to have a space after the value indicator (`:`), and you meant to do:

```
        include: false
        transitions:
```

or you need to quote your multi-line scalar:

```
        'include:false
        transitions':
```

or you need to put that plain scalar on one line:

```
        include:false transitions:
```

please note that some libraries do not allow value indicators in a plain scalar at all, even if they are not followed by space

Answer (score 24):

I fixed this for myself by simply realizing I had indented a line too far, and un-indenting it.

Comment: Same here. Had an if else block and had a couple spaces on the line under my  {{ if }} block which caused this error. Thanks!

Comment: Copied from another file and the indenting was off by 1. I hate yaml.

Answer (score 9):

we need to use space before ":"
Then it will excecute
check the yaml script in below
http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: it should be space after ":"

Answer (score 6):

I was working in a Helm chart. My issue was the markup

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create -}}
serviceAccountName: {{ include "myapp.serviceAccountName" . }}
{{- end }}
```

The problem was the `-` at the end of the `if` expression. Removing that `-` resolved the issue

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.create }}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue, changing  `{{- end -}}` to `{{- end }}` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

There are couple of issues in the yaml file, with yaml files it gets messy, fortunately it can be identified easily with tools like [yaml lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-lint)

Install it

```
npm install -g yaml-lint
```

Here is how you can validate

```
E:\githubRepos\prometheus-sql-exporter-usage\etc>yamllint prometheus.yaml
√ YAML Lint successful.
```

Comment: I get "YAML Lint successful", but running `docker-compose up` still throws the same `mapping values are not allowed in this context` error, so I guess your answer isn't really working for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was a unicode '-' from a cut and paste.  Visualy it looked OK, but the character was 'EN DASH' (U+2013) instead of 'HYPHEN MINUS' (U+002D)

Answer (score 2):

In mine case it was the space after the `:` in a value:

```yaml
query-url: https://blabla.com/blabla?label=blabla: blabla
```

To fix:

```yaml
query-url: https://blabla.com/blabla?label=blabla:%20blabla
```

Or:

```yaml
query-url: "https://blabla.com/blabla?label=blabla: blabla"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using powershell and have copied the `cat` command, it won't work properly (I'm guessing it is encoding the content in some way). Instead of using `"$(cat file.yaml)"` you should use `$(Get-Content file.yaml -Raw)` without the quotes.

Really annoying!

Answer (score -1):

In my case if was some odd disappearing of the initial formatting of the initial chart that was copied in Intellij Idea. It was possible to gfigure out with text-compare tool only:

[image]

So, when you do your copy and paste in your IDE, please double check is what you have copied is exactly what you paste, aren't some additional spaces were added.