# How to use composite custom action in a self-hosted Windows runner?

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have defined a composite custom action in my repository at **.github/actions/my-custom-action/action.yml**, and I want to use it in a workflow job that runs on a Windows self-hosted runner.

To do that, I am specifying a relative path in my workflow file:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Execute custom action
    uses: ./.github/actions/my-custom-action/
```

However, when the job is executed on a self hosted runner in a Windows machine, I get the following error:

```
C:\actions-runner\_work\repo-name\repo-name\./.github/actions/deploySumex/action.yml: (Line: 31, Col: 11, Idx: 660) - (Line: 31, Col: 11, Idx: 660): Mapping values are not allowed in this context.
```

If I change the relative path to:

`uses: .\.github\actions\my-custom-action\`

or

`uses:  .github\actions\my-custom-action\`

or using the full path:

`uses: C:\github-runner\_work\repo-name\repo-name\.github\actions\my-custom-action\`

I get the following error right after I commit the changes:

`the 'uses' attribute must be a path, a Docker image, or owner/repo@ref`

My repository is private so I can not use the sintax for actions in a
subdirectory of a public repository

`uses: {owner}/{repo}/{path}@{ref}`

Could you help me figure out how to use my composite custom action in a Windows self-hosted runner?

**Update**
As requested by GuiFalourd, this is my custom action YAML file:
name: "Composite action Test"

```
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: step 1
        run: |
          Write-Host "Hello"

    - name: step 2
        run: |
          Write-Host "world"
```

Comment: Could you add the `action.yaml` file implementation to the question? The issue seems related to this file, line 31.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "mapping values are not allowed in this context " error in yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612042/how-to-fix-mapping-values-are-not-allowed-in-this-context-error-in-yaml-file)

Answer (score 0):

[GuiFalourd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8496462/guifalourd) was right on his comment, the problem was not in the way I was setting the path in the caller job. The problem was in the composite YAML action. It seems to be related to the use of double quotes. I refactored my YAML, and now it's working

```
name: "Hello World"
description: "Greet someone"
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: Write-host 'Hello world'
      shell: powershell
```

Now I´m using single quotes in

> run: Write-host 'Hello world'

I also needed to add a Shell

> shell: powershell